# Using Microsoft Office Interop to create and parse Excel spreadsheets from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office-interop

I have a new ASP.NET MVC project that has two requirements that require using the Office Interop DLLs to generate Excel spreadsheet files in Excel 2003 format by combining several template files into a multi-sheet workbook and to parse these files once filled in. The files we parse may come back in Excel 2003, 2007 or 2010 format (I believe 2007 and 2010 file formats are identical but feel free to correct me on that).

I'd be much happier if we could convince the (internal) clients to drop this requirement. They have been made aware of the risks in this type of work and still want to go ahead so now I'm looking for good references to help get us started and have had some trouble narrowing down the correct keywords to search for.

Thanks.

Comment: Using Interop dlls on the server side is really a bad idea... I have tried once, and it did not work.... Try Aspose Cells, I have used Aspose Word and I was very satisfied. It is not free, but it worked great for me.... (No, I have no connection to Aspose, I have just used it and liked it....)

Comment: Have you read this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: Yeah you guys are right. I had my concerns about taking the approach I described above and soon after posting this question I found the document Ahmad linked to. We've been told there's no budget for purchasing additional tools like Aspose so are going to try using the open source libraries ExcelLibrary for Excel 2003 support and ExcelPackage for 2007 support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Excel interop on the server is a reallyy bad idea. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Alternatives are:

*Open source*

**Excel 2003**

- ExcelLibrary http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/downloads/list

  - Note from [another commenter:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic#comment4403140_2603625)
  - > ExcelLibrary has been superseded by the exceptional [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com) - epplus.codeplex.com. Jan updates it regularly. Have been using it and it is one of the finest open source projects we've worked with. – Mark A Nov 4 '10 at 0:11
- NPOI http://npoi.codeplex.com/

**Excel 2007**

- ExcelPackage http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/

*Commercial*

- Aspose Cells http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx

Comment: can we use this for parsing doc type file if yes then how to do that